# Number of times contacted/Viewed

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to develop an Apex trigger for an Object Lead. Requirement is like count number of times that record viewed.

I am Sharing my Code with you.

//Code Starts from here.

```
trigger ContactedRecord on Lead (after insert,after update) {

List<ID> lid=new List<ID>();

for(Lead l:Trigger.new)
{
    lid.add(l.id);
}

Integer i=0;
List<Lead> leadlist=[Select id,No_of_Times_Contacted__c from Lead where id IN:lid];

System.debug('**List size**'+leadlist.size());

for(Lead li: leadlist)
{
    /*Lead l=new Lead();
    Lead olddata=Trigger.oldMap.get(li.id);*/

    system.debug('No of Contacts');

    if(li.size()>0)
    {
        for(Integer j=0;j<li.Size(0);j++)
        {
            if(li.No_of_Times_Contacted__c ==li[j].id)
            {
                i++;
                li[j].No_of_Times_Contacted__c =i;
            }
        }
    }

    update li;
}
```

The code is not working Properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
trigger ContactedRecord on Lead (before insert, before update) {

    for(Lead li : Trigger.new) {

        li.No_of_Times_Contacted__c = li.No_of_Times_Contacted__c!=null ? li.No_of_Times_Contacted__c+1 : 1;

       }
}
```

Comment: As @Simon Lawrence explained you ca not use After trigger in this scenario.

Comment: (edited to remove list that was not needed!)

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify/update leads in the Lead **after** triggers.. as they have already been committed to the database layer by this point in the transaction. You need to make your trigger a BEFORE update or insert trigger, and then all you need to do is set the field value to the incremented value (ie. you don't need the DML as this is before they are committed any way).

I would also add, this won't provide a count of how many times a lead is viewed, only how many times a lead is updated (ie. edited and saved). The mechanism for counting views is much more complicated in Salesforce sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use trigger in this scenario.

Generally to track how many times a record is been viewed follow the below steps,

1.Create a custom object.
2.In loading a detail page of the object (for which you want track view history)you can write a simple java script to create the record in that custom object which is been created via step1.
Sample code for creating record via Javascript,

```
sforce.connection.sessionId = sessionIds; //Used for Session out    
var trackResult = new sforce.SObject("Custom object name__c");
/*List of fields in custom object like record ID and object name*/
trackResult.AppLabel__c=record.id;
var result = sforce.connection.create([trackResult]);
```

You can generate a report out from that custom object to get number of times a record is been viewed.